# ArrayList how do I store the input I've put , into a list Java

Tags: java, arraylist

So basically I have a menu to make, involving this.

> 1. List of clients ( when pressing this it should load the list of clients I've added).
> 2. Add clients ( adding clients )
> 3. Edit clients
> 4. remove client.

The place where I need help is the list of clients, when I press nr 2 ( Add clients and insert a name, I want it to be saved into the list of clients, but I can't figure it out how to do, I m very new to java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Friends {

        public static ArrayList clients=new ArrayList<>();

        public static void a(){


        }


        public static void b (){


        }

        public static void c(){
            System.out.println("c");
        }

        public static void printMenu(){
            System.out.println("==========================");
            System.out.println("Main menu");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("1 - List clients");
            System.out.println("2 - Add clients");
            System.out.println("3 - Edit client");
            System.out.println("4 - Remove Client");
            System.out.println("0  -Exit");
            System.out.println("==========================");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");

        }

        public static int getUserMenu(Scanner s){
            String input = s.nextLine();
            int number = -1;

            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){

            }

            return number;
        }

        public static ArrayList<Integer> addClient(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in);

            System.out.print("Please enter a client: ");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            clients.add(input);
            System.out.println("");


            System.out.println("You have added new client : " + clients);        
            System.out.println("");

            for(int i=0;i<clients.size();i++);
                    {
                        System.out.println("There are " + clients.size());
                    }

            return clients;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in);
            int choice= -1;        

                while( choice != 0) {
                printMenu();
                choice = getUserMenu(sc);

                switch ( choice )
                {
                case 1: a(); break;
                case 2: b(); addClient();
                break;
                case 3: c(); break;
                case 0 : System.out.println("Bye!"); break;
                default : System.out.println("Invalid number!");break;

                }

            }
                sc.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You did when you ran `clients.add(input)`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your real issue is that you are having difficulty *printing* the list correctly, and that is leading you to think that you haven't added the inputs to the list.   (In fact ... I think you have ... )

Here's your attempt to print the list:

```
    for(int i=0;i<clients.size();i++);
            {
                System.out.println("There are " + clients.size());
            }
```

There are two problems with this:

1. The body of the loop just prints the list size.  If you want to print (say) the `i`th element, you need to call `clients.get(i)`.
2. In fact, that loop body is NOT the loop body at all.  Look at the statement that starts `for(int i=`.  Now look at the end of that line.  Do you see the semicolon?  That is the body of the `for` loop!  Yes ... an *empty statement*!!

   Get rid of that semicolon, it should not be there.